# Casting a primitive to a custom class

Tags: java, casting, char, int

I am trying to do something concerning the primitive `char.` By itself, one could use

```
((int)char)
```

to get the integer value of that character. However, due to the way this is formatted, I cannot do this. Is there a way to allow casting of a certain class, such as CustomInt, and determine which characters turn into what number?

Example:

```
((int)'A') == 68;
((CustomInt)'A') == 0;
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That is completely impossible.  You need to write a regular method.

Comment: Despite the primitives (including Auto(un)boxing), Java allows casting only along the Object hierachy. So the answer is: if you want the typecast syntax then no, this is not possible in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. Write a method `public static CustomInt valueOf(char x)` instead.